# How to automate compile less css without less js

Tags: php, less

I am a newbie in lesscss.

```
using JavaScript is discouraged at the production stage as it will badly affect the website performance
```

> In future, I will deploy PHP code on `apache server`.
>
> How to compile less css without node.js. Is there any alternative to
>   compile lesscss before hand.

Case:

After changes in lesscss, I will `automate compile my all less css files` instead to go for manual because It will become tough for me to compile each less css file.

For automation what should I do?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest setup for compiling LESS beforehand is covered in the official ["Using Less" documentation](http://lesscss.org/#using-less) ("Installation" and "Command Line Usage" sections). Basically you'll do

```
$ npm install -g less
$ lessc inputfilename.less outputfilename.css
```

If you make a main LESS file that imports the rest, you'll only have to run one `lessc` command. for example, main.less (the name could be anything) might look like

```
@import 'myfirstfile';
@import 'somedirectory/anotherfile';
@import 'somedirectory/yetanother';
```

and you'd just run `lessc main.less main.css`